# modify nested json array to more pretty style object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have this json file how can I simplify it more

note: I can't modify the json it's coming from backend api that i have no control of

> exampleJSON:

```
[
  {
    "Supermarket":[
      {
        "Food Cupboard":[
          "Grains &amp; Rice",
          "Pasta &amp; Noodles",
          "Cooking Oil",
          "Vinegar",
          "Sauce &amp; Dressings",
          "Sugars &amp; Sweeteners",
          "Flour",
          "Herbs &amp; Spices"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Beverages":[
          "Juices",
          "Soft Drinks",
          "Coffee, Tea &amp; Cocoa",
          "Water",
          "Powdered Drink Mixes &amp; Flavorings"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

> what I need the result to be

```
{
  "Supermarket":{
    "Food Cupboard":[
      "Grains &amp; Rice",
      "Pasta &amp; Noodles",
      "Cooking Oil",
      "Vinegar",
      "Sauce &amp; Dressings",
      "Sugars &amp; Sweeteners",
      "Flour",
      "Herbs &amp; Spices"
    ],
    "Beverages":[
      "Juices",
      "Soft Drinks",
      "Coffee, Tea &amp; Cocoa",
      "Water",
      "Powdered Drink Mixes &amp; Flavorings"
    ]
  }
}
```

then I tried mapping through the whole json and assigning different values and keys but didn't work
can you help me with that

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (and get a badge). Your question lacks any attempt at solving this problem on your own. The idea is for you to try to get something to work and then come here with specific problems you are unable to resolve. Taking the tour and reading about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center will provide all the information you need.

Comment: "_I tried mapping through the whole json and assigning different values and keys_" - Show us what you tried and explain what didn't work...then we can go from there.

Comment: or just wait, and someone will just do your work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.reduce` to group the `Supermarket` items into one object:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "Supermarket":[
      {
        "Food Cupboard":[
          "Grains &amp; Rice", "Pasta &amp; Noodles", "Cooking Oil", "Vinegar", "Sauce &amp; Dressings", "Sugars &amp; Sweeteners", "Flour", "Herbs &amp; Spices" ]
      },
      {
        "Beverages":[ "Juices", "Soft Drinks", "Coffee, Tea &amp; Cocoa", "Water", "Powdered Drink Mixes &amp; Flavorings" ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

const res = data.map(e => {
  const current = {...e};
  current.Supermarket = 
    current.Supermarket.reduce((acc, item) => Object.assign(acc, item), {});
  return current;
});

console.log(res);
```